# Spring webflux: keeping an EntityManager open during the whole process of a reactive request handling

Tags: java, spring, jpa, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

In the standard synchronous Spring (WebMVC) world, there are `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` and `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` that hold a JPA `EntityManager` open during the whole processing of a request and allow to avoid the annoying `LazyInitializationException` ('no Session').

`OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` also works in a similar way for async servlet API-based applications.

But how do you deal with this problem in a Webflux application? Let's say I have a Webflux controller that does something like

```
service.getOneReactively(...).flatMapMany(one -> obtainAFlux(one))
```

where `service.getOneReactively()` finds a domain object in the database and `obtainAFlux()` accesses a lazy collection on that domain object causing its load. Both calls will be executed on some thread pool, probably on different threads, so Hibernate's `Session` bound to the first thread (where the domain object is materialized) will not be accessible in the second thread (where the collection is loaded).

This results in `LazyInitializationException`.

How do you solve such a problem? The only thing I could invent so far is to pack both calls into a method and call it in a transaction in one reactive call.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate is not reactive, it uses JDBC which is a blocking database driver, and it in turn uses threadlocal to store session information which is not possible to use in Webflux.

If you wish to do blocking database calls you must use `Mono.fromCallable` and assign the calls to its own Scheduler so that it gets its own dedicate thread. You can read more about it here in the documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking hibernate cant natively return a Flux.

Your code should look something like this

```
Flux<Objects> myObjects = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {

    // make all your calls to the database here
    // build then your flux or whatever you want

    return Flux.fromIterable(listOfObjects);
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()); // Makes sure this is run in its own thread
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Toerktumlare mentioned, Hibernate is not reactive, it uses JDBC which is a blocking database driver, but  you can use [Hibernate reactive](http://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.0/reference/html_single/) and use non-blocking methods and `sessions`.
a simple code example must be like this:

```
public Flux<MyUser> findAll() {
    try {
        Mutiny.SessionFactory factory = CustomEntityManagerFactoryPostgresImpl
                .getInstance()
                .getEntityManagerFactory()
                .unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);

        CriteriaBuilder builder = factory.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<MyUser> criteria = builder.createQuery(MyUser.class);
        Root<MyUser> root = criteria.from(MyUser.class);

        Flux<MyUser> myUser = Flux.fromIterable(
            factory.withSession(
                    session -> session
                            .createQuery(criteria)
                            .getResultList()
            ).await().indefinitely());
        factory.close();
        return myUser;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        log.error(String.valueOf(exception));
        return Flux.empty();
    }
```

and a `mono<>` is like:

```
public Mono<MyUser> getOneUser(Long id) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-persistence");
    Mutiny.SessionFactory sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);
    Mutiny.Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    try {
        return Mono.fromFuture(session.find(MyUser.class, id).subscribe().asCompletionStage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using blocking JPA API in a WebFlux application should be avoided.

If you want to access the RDBMS in a Spring WebFlux application, try to use the reactive streams API(none-blocking) instead.

1. Use Spring R2dbc/Spring Data R2dbc instead, see [my Spring R2dbc example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample).
2. Use Hibernate Reactive, currently, there is no official Spring/Hibernate Reactive integration, but it is easy to integrate them.

   - Create a `persistence.xml` file.
   - Create a `Mutiny.SessionFactory` bean.
   - Use `Mutiny.SessionFactory` to handle RDBMS operations,see the [PostRepository example](https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/blob/master/mutiny-spring-hibernate/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java) written in Hiberante Reactvie.

   The complete [Spring/Hibernate reactive example](https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/tree/master/mutiny-spring-hibernate) can be found on my Github (but the web handling is using Vertx).
3. Mixed blocking JPA in a Spring Webflux application **should be avoided**. But it is possible, see [my example which mixed JPA and R2dbc](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-playground/tree/master/jpa-r2dbc) in a single application.

And the Open session in view pattern is desginated to work in a traditional servlet container and depends on Spring WebMVC.